# Angular ui-select only highlighting first choice in list

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I'm using ui-select quite a bit in different ways on an app. The selects work but all have one thing in common where only the top choice is ever highlighted. I would really like to see the selected item highlighted if the list is reopened. Other than that is there a way to turn off the highlighting all together?
Here is a sample:

```
<ui-select reset-search-input="false"
    id="entryGenModuleType"
    name="entryGenModuleType"
    ng-model="deForm.moduleTypeId" theme="select2" append-to-body="true"
    class="holdSelect"
    ng-change="filterSavedEntries()"
    ng-disabled=""
    title="Select Module Type">
<ui-select-match allow-clear="true"
    placeholder="">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat=" type in selectionData.moduleTypes | orderBy:'name' | filter: { name: $select.search } ">
 <span ng-bind-html="type.name"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: No one can tell me why the highlighting is not working correctly?

Comment: I have noticed that if I use arrow keys and then select an option by using 'Enter', the selected option is then highlighted. Just not if I select using mouse click, where the top option is always highlighted.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the same issue.
Removing attribute `reset-search-input="false"` help for me

Comment: Thanks. This works as long as I don't need to keep the search string, which I need in some cases. This fixes most areas. It's a shame that the attribute breaks this. I have some long lists of similar strings users have to search and would like to keep their search string and where they left off. Had used different solution and had moved on is why the long response time.